# Where is complex Log continuous

Tags: complex-analysis

Write down the biggest subset $D$ of $\mathbb C$ on which ${\rm Log(z)}$ is a continuous function. Explain why ${\rm Log(z)}$ is not continuous at points outside $D.$

Anyone know the answer to this?

Comment: [Related...](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2914)

Comment: My answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88341/branch-cut-and-logz-derivative/88358#88358 might help...

Answer (score 2):

I'll tell you one possible answer, and you tell me why (I'm assuming the principal branch):

Answer: $D$ is the complex plane minus the non-positive reals.

Hint: Follow things in a semi-circle and observe the "jump" in angles.